# Samsung Galaxy S2 takes a long time to get GPS signal

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, settings, gps

My Samsung Galaxy S2 takes a long time to get a GPS signal (maybe around 5 minutes). Anyone know why and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [FasterFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Double.FasterFix&hl=en) from the Play Store and follow the prompts.